# where are user created objects stored?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, rdbms

In Oracle each user is a schema, and by default each user's created objects are created in to their schema.

In MySQL users and their privileges are stored in `mysql.user`, but when they creates objects where are they created?

Is there any concept of a schema for each user?

Can we create a separate schema for tables and indexes like Oracle in MySQL?

Answer (score 2):

As defined in the [MySQL Glossary](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/glossary.html#glos_schema):

```
In MySQL, physically, a schema is synonymous with a database. 
You can substitute the keyword SCHEMA instead of DATABASE in MySQL SQL syntax, 
for example using CREATE SCHEMA instead of CREATE DATABASE.

Some other database products draw a distinction. For example, in the Oracle 
Database product, a schema represents only a part of a database: the tables 
and other objects owned by a single user.
```

Comment: Thanks for quick and positive reply!

Comment: But still I am not sure when any user creates any objects, does it stores in current in use database?

Comment: And still is it possible to create a separate database/schema to maintain indexes? for performance improvement?

Comment: There is a ton of material at http://www.mysql.com/.  Download a version and try it out.  It is easy and quick to install and trial.